# Нужна ли запятая перед «чтобы»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, причастный-оборот

Нужна ли запятая перед "чтобы" в этом предложении?
*...это клуб, созданный, **чтобы** побеждать на льду...*

Answer (score 2):

Запятая нужна: .*..это клуб, созданный, **чтобы побеждать на льду**...*

Придаточное цели входит в причастный оборот и **обособляется.** Вопросы могут возникнуть в связи с произношением: пауза там произносительная, но **не подчеркнутая.** Запятая ставится по грамматическому принципу, без учета интонации.

**Примеры:**

Может, это всё лабиринт, **созданный, чтобы** привести меня туда, с чего я начал.

Это самый эффективный продукт, когда-либо **созданный, чтобы** манипулировать человеческими эмоциями.

Comment: В поддержку Вашего ответа: *Святое озеро — это, по существу, гигантский пруд, искусственно **созданный, чтобы** заставить жить и работать все жизнеобеспечивающие механизмы монастыря* (Д. С. Лихачев. Воспоминания).

Comment: Спасибо за дополнение.